# Clicking back button twice to exit from application in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

How to exit from an application by clicking the back button twice on your mobile?

for going back to the previous page i have done this

```
 Keys.onBackPressed: {
    stackView.push("previous.qml")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Keys.onBackPressed: {
    timer.pressBack()
}
Timer{
    id: timer
    
    property bool backPressed: false
    repeat: false
    interval: 200//ms
    onTriggered: backPressed = false
    function pressBack(){
        if(backPressed){
            timer.stop()
            backPressed = false
            // leave application
            // your code
            leaveApp()
        }
        else{
            backPressed = true
            timer.start()
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a timer to do this, within 50ms if you press twice on back this will run leaveApp().

Comment: I would use JS for that, I mean storing `data1 = new Date()` on the first click and calculating the interval `new Date().getTime() - data1.getTime()` on the second one.

Comment: I have tried this code, but it's not working, when i press back button twice nothing happens

Comment: 50ms was too fast, i increased  interval to 200ms. You can eventually adapt this code to use new Date() instead Timer.